# AppointmentId of meeting item deleted or cancelled from Calendar

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, exchange-server-2010

I am developing an Add-In that needs to do a function when I delete / cancel a meeting.

I used the code:

```
Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Folder calendarFolder = app.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Folder;
 _calcitems.ItemRemove += CalcitemsItemRemove;
```

The event CalcItemsRemove is called every time something is removed from the CalenderFolder.

Strangely this event is called even if the meeting item got accepted.

My question is how to identify

-> If an appointment is deleted from the calender Item.
-> If an appointment is cancelled

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a meeting appointment, Outlook automatically creates a tentative appointment in the Calendar. When you explicitly accept the invitation in the Inbox, Outlook deletes the tentative appointment and creates a brand new item. This is done to counter a problem when a user accepts a meeting on one machine, then deletes the invitation from another machine connected to the same Exchange mailbox (I just accepted it, right? Let's get rid of the invitation) - if invitation is deleted, Outlook deletes the appointment that the user just accepted from another machine.

When the appointment is recreated, Items.ItemAdd event will fire. You can treat it as a brand new appointment.